# Existe diferença entre flex-basis, flex-grow e width? Qual é a recomendação de uso delas em um container Flex?

Tags: html, css, css3, layout-responsivo, flexbox

Estou com uma duvida técnica sobre a utilização das propriedade `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` e `width`. Repare que na imagem abaixo eu consegui o mesmo resultado usando as 3 propriedades.

Ai fiquei na dúvida, se as 3 propriedades fazem a mesma coisa o que devo considerar para escolher entre uma e outra?

Existe de fato alguma diferença técnica entre uma e outra, ou posso usar qualquer uma delas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 20px;
}
.container.b .box {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
.container.w .box {
    width: 50%;
}
.container.f .box {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>pai flex e filho com flex-basis</p>
<div class="container b">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<p>pai flex e filho com width</p>
<div class="container w">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<p>pai flex e filho com flex-grow</p>
<div class="container f">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uma explicação com bastante exemplos: https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/

Comment: Esse guia é muito bom mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### flex-basis

Define a largura inicial do elemento. A largura do elemento é flexível, podendo aumentar caso não haja quebra de linha, mas também a largura pode ser reduzida caso outro elemento a force. No exemplo abaixo o `.box2` do primeiro `.container` não há quebra de linha (por causa do `&nbsp;`) e seu conteúdo, por ser muito largo, força a largura do `.box1` ser menor do que foi definido no `flex-basis` de 50%.

**Exemplo:**

```css
.container{
   display: flex;
}

.box{
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.box1{
   flex-basis: 50%;
}

.box2{
   flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1">
      box1 - mínimo 50% do container, com quebra de linha
   </div>
   <div class="box box2">
      box2&nbsp;-&nbsp;mínimo&nbsp;20%&nbsp;do&nbsp;container,&nbsp;sem&nbsp;quebra&nbsp;de&nbsp;linha
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1">
      box1 - mínimo 50% do container, com quebra de linha
   </div>
   <div class="box box2">
      box2
   </div>
</div>
```

> ### flex-grow

Define a largura do elemento em relação aos outros elementos do mesmo container. Se houver apenas 1 elemento, irá ocupar a largura toda, pois não há com quem ser comparado.

O valor dessa propriedade é numérico, ou seja, não possui uma unidade de medida (`px`, `%`, `vw` etc.). O CSS irá somar todos os valores dos `flex-grow` dos elementos e dividir a largura do container entre eles proporcionalmente ao seu valor.

**Exemplo:**

```css
.container{
   display: flex;
   min-height: 20px;
}

.box{
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.box1{
   flex-grow: 1;
}

.box2{
   flex-grow: 4;
}

.box3{
   flex-grow: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1">
   </div>
   <div class="box box2">
   </div>
   <div class="box box3">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1">
      box1
   </div>
   <div class="box box2">
   </div>
   <div class="box box3">
   </div>
</div>
```

Veja que no primeiro container o `.box1` e `.box2` ocupam exatamente a metade do container, isso porque somando os valores dos 3 boxes vazios (1 + 4 + 5 = 10), logo 1 + 4 = 5, a metade do total de 10.

Repare também que no segundo container há texto no `.box1`, e o espaço ocupado pelo texto é considerado pelo `flex-grow`. Em razão disso, há uma redução forçada do `.box3` proporcional à largura ocupada pelo texto do `.box1`.

> ### width

Define uma largura fixa ao elemento. Mesmo que não haja quebra de linha, a largura não é flexível e se o conteúdo ultrapassar a largura do elemento, ele não se expande.

**Exemplo:**

```css
.container{
   display: flex;
}

.box{
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.box1{
   width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1">
      Texto&nbsp;sem&nbsp;quebra&nbsp;de&nbsp;linha
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1">
      Texto com quebra de linha
   </div>
</div>
```

---

As diferenças técnicas são as acima, então você deve usar a que melhor for conveniente. O que você pode considerar para usar uma delas, além da sua necessidade, é a questão de compatibilidade, principalmente as propriedades `flex-basis` e `flex-grow`, que são especificações mais modernas. Veja as tabelas informadas pelo site [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com) (ambas possuem a mesma tabela e observações):

[**flex-basis** e **flex-grow**](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex-basis)

Comment: Muito boa explicação Tio!

Answer (score 3):

Obteve o mesmo por uma inocente coincidência, isto é, nesta situação em particular resultou na mesma coisa, sendo dois elementos filhos e usando 50%. Nem sempre - na verdade quase nunca - terá essa sorte em desenvolvimento.

- `width` define a largura do elemento, não importa o resto;
- `flex-basis` define a referência inicial do elemento **antes** de distribuir o espaço;
- `flex-grow` define como o espaço do elemento pai será distribuído entre os filhos;

Devemos lembrar que, por omissão, [`flex` terá o valor `0 1 auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property), o que configura `flex-grow` como 0, `flex-shrink` como 1 e `flex-basis` como `auto`.

## Width

Assim, utilizando `width` nos elementos filhos com o pai `flex` terá um comportamento peculiar devido ao fato que por ser `flex` o espaço será distribuído entre os filhos enlargando-os conforme suas regras ou encurtando-os se ocorrer *overflow* no elemento pai. Acontece que colocar `width: 50%` em dois elementos filhos você mascara o comportamento de `flex`, pois naturalmente irá ocupará toda a largura do elemento pai, sem overflow. Porém, tente colocar mais elementos filhos ou uma largura maior que 50%:

**Elemento pai flex com filhos maiores que 50%**

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
}

.filhos {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filhos">short</div>
  <div class="filhos">looooooooooooooong</div>
</div>
```

O que acontece é que a propriedade `width: 80%` será ignorada devido a ocorrer overflow no elemento pai e, portanto, os 80% deixam de ser seguidos, mantendo a regra básica definida por `flex`.

**Elemento pai flex com mais de dois filhos**

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
}

.filhos {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filhos">short</div>
  <div class="filhos">looooooooooooooong</div>
  <div class="filhos">short</div>
</div>
```

De forma semelhante, quando há mais de dois elementos com largura 50% novamente ocorreria o overflow no elemento pai, fazendo os elementos reduzirem a aproximadamente 33% da largura total (para 3 filhos).

Ou seja, o `width` não faz o que parece fazer, só produziu o resultado esperado por coincidência de ter utilizado os valores corretos.

## Flex-grow

A [propriedade `flex-grow`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-grow) determina como o espaço livre disponível no elemento pai será distribuído para os elementos filhos. Você utilizou `flex-grow: 1`, o que determina que todos os elementos filhos irão crescer de modo equivalente. A coincidência que ocorreu neste caso foi que ambos os elementos possuem exatamente o mesmo conteúdo: nenhum. Possuindo o mesmo conteúdo os elementos irão crescer de forma idêntica, porém se um dos elementos possuir uma largura de conteúdo diferente do outro, isso não ocorre. Vejamos um exemplo:

**Elementos filhos com flex-grow:1 e conteúdo distinto**

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
}

.filhos {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filhos">short</div>
  <div class="filhos">looooooooooooooong</div>
  <div class="filhos">short</div>
</div>
```

O segundo filho possui um conteúdo diferente dos outros dois. Não só diferente como maior. Determinamos ainda que o espaço livre do elemento pai deve ser dividido de forma igualitária para os elementos filhos - e isso não significa que os filhos terão a mesma largura no final. Se eu quero dividir R$ 30,00 de forma igual entre 3 pessoas, darei R$ 10,00 a cada uma. Se uma das três pessoas já tiver inicialmente mais dinheiro que as outras, ela naturalmente terá mais dinheiro depois que eu der os R$ 10,00. O mesmo acontece com os elementos filhos. Inspecione o resultado do exemplo acima e verá que o segundo elemento possuirá uma largura maior que os outros dois.

O que define a largura de referência é justamente `flex-basis`. Como comentamos inicialmente, por omissão `flex-basis` terá o valor `auto`, que levará em consideração o valor de `width`, que por omissão também terá o valor `auto`. Assim, os elementos crescem considerando a largura inicial.

## Flex-basis

A [propriedade `flex-basis`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property) determinará qual será a referência para que um elemento cresça dentro de um elemento `flex`. Por omissão o valor será `auto`, o que, dependendo do elemento, irá considerar a largura mínima do elemento conforme o seu conteúdo, porém você pode determinar uma largura específica como referência e todos os elementos serão redimensionados a partir dela.

**Elementos filhos com flex-basis: 50%**

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
}

.filhos {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filhos">short</div>
  <div class="filhos">looooooooooooooong</div>
  <div class="filhos">short</div>
</div>
```

O que acontecerá neste exemplo é que, diferente de apenas utilizar o `flex-grow`, a largura de referência será 50% do elemento pai. Desta forma, os três elementos filhos partirão da mesma largura de referência e quando redimensionados pelo flex possuirão a mesma largura final. Ao inspecionar o resultado verá que os três elementos possuem a mesma largura. A coincidência foi ter apenas dois elementos filhos, partindo da mesma largura de referência, sendo redimensionados para o mesmo valor final.

Concluindo, as três propriedades não fazem a mesma coisa. A `width` determina a largura do elemento, independente da forma que irá redimensionar; a `flex-grow` determina como o elemento será redimensionado considerando o espaço vazio no elemento pai e `flex-basis` determina qual a largura de referência antes de redimensionar o elemento com `flex-grow`.

> O que devo considerar para escolher entre uma e outra?

Você não considera entre uma ou outra, elas são complementares entre si e utiliza as que necessitar para obter o resultado desejado.

- Preciso de elementos que ocupem metade do elemento pai: `width: 50%`, sem `flex`;
- Preciso de elementos que ocupem toda a largura do elemento pai crescendo de forma igual: `flex-grow: 1`;
- Preciso de elementos que cresçam a partir de um mesmo valor: `flex-basis: 1`;

Para o seu exemplo, se precisa que os elementos tenham **sempre** 50% da largura do elemento pai, utilize o `width: 50%` e esqueça o `flex`. Se você quer que eles **cresçam** até ocuparem todo o elemento pai, utilize `flex-grow: 1`. Se você precisa que ao final eles possuam a mesma largura, utilize `flex-basis` para definir a mesma referência.

Comment: Valeu Anderson isso ajuda bastante a clarear as ideia!